# What can cause a Laravel request input to be empty?

Tags: php, json, laravel, http

I'm posting some data to a Laravel api endpoint:

```
POST {{authority}}/api/feedback HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

{
    "message": "Well done! I really like your app.",
    "specs": "Device Info",
}
```

But the data is not in the request:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FeedbackController extends Controller
{
    public function feedback(Request $request)
    {
        // this works fine:
        // $inputs = file_get_contents('php://input');

        // this gives an empty array:
        $inputs = $request->all();

        dd($inputs);

        return 'just testing';
    }
}
```

What could cause this to happen?

Laravel v8.79.0, php v8.0.14

Comment: wrong format of the input. how are you sending them ?

Comment: Is the final comma in the JSON payload causing issues?

Comment: Ah yes, good spot by @waterloomatt . technically `{
    "message": "Well done! I really like your app.",
    "specs": "Device Info",
}` is invalid JSON due to the comma after the last property. Running json_decode on this [will fail](https://3v4l.org/MvFaL).

Comment: Thanks for spotting the json error! :facepalm: Drove me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are expecting a json and ass the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-json-input-values) specifies better use the input method to access json objects.

example:

> $name = $request->input('user.name');
> or
> $input = $request->input();
> for all inputs

Comment: I think this is the right answer. In addition you can use `$request->json()->all()`, https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_json

Comment: inputs are inputs, no matter how you access them, the `input({input_name}, {default_value})` method is recommended to use for the default value parameter wich is `null` by default.